# Git changes based on another branch?

Tags: git

I am so confused by git right now. I have created two branches, one of which is created from master, and the other is created from that branch... like this :

```
master -> Branch1
            |
          Branch2
```

Branch2 is feature work that relies on some changes from Branch1.

I created these branches as follows :

```
git checkout -b Branch1
git checkout -b Branch2 Branch1
```

But when I make changes in Branch2, and then switch back to Branch1, the diff still shows the changes, and if I commit, and push, it will push all the changes to Branch1.

Where the hell did I go wrong? And how do I fix this mess?

EDIT :

Adding .git/config for reference...

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = <REPO URL>
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[branch "BRANCH1"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/BRANCH1
[branch "BRANCH2"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/BRANCH2
```

Comment: How about commit (and push if you want) when you are on branch2 **then** switch back to branch1 (or stash if you don't want to commit)

Comment: The content of `.git/config` doesn't help. If you learned from a tutorial or some other source to edit `.git/config` then drop that tutorial and find a better one. `.git/config` is not meant to be manually edited. And there is no need to manually edit it. Use [`git config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) to change the repository configuration. The fact that it updates `.git/config` is just an implementation detail; it can change any time.

Comment: I didn't edit it manually - does anybody know how I fix this mess?

Comment: Git has 3 main working areas (4 with stash) on your local env:
**1)** Git Working Directory (new files/or new changes)
**2)** Git Index
**3)** Git local repo
You move changes from Working Directory to Index with `git add`
From Index to local repo with `git commit`
From local to remote with `git push`
If the file is new and has never been tracked then is shown as untracked in every branch. You can check that using `git status`
Have fun

Comment: I fixed it! By switching the team to SVN - everything works now. Life is good.